# How can I make a hotkey trigger a Windows Forms button?

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys

I have a button on a form to which I wish to assign a hot-key:

```
namespace WebBrowser
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int GetPixel(int x, int y)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            Graphics grp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            grp.CopyFromScreen(new Point(x,y), Point.Empty, new Size(1,1));
            grp.Save();
            return bmp.GetPixel(0, 0).ToArgb();
        }

        // THIS! How can I make a hot-key trigger this button?
        //
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Cursor.Position.X;
            int y = Cursor.Position.Y;
            int pixel = GetPixel(x,y);
            textBox1.Text = pixel.ToString();
        }

        void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious : what really is the purpose of the button here ? Do you only want the code in the current ButtonClick handler to be executed when the end-user has the cursor somewhere within the WebBrowser Control bounds ? Or do you want to "snapshot" the color under the cursor anywhere in the Form's bounds, including over the Button itself ?

Comment: Override the form's [`ProcessCmdKey` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a Windows Forms project with a `WebBrowser` control: the `WebBrowser` will "eat the keystrokes" anytime it has focus, even if Form KeyPreview is set to 'true'.

Use the WebBrowser PreviewKeyDown event to call the button click:

```
    private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs event)
    {
        // Possibly filter here for certain keystrokes?
        // Using e.KeyCode, e.KeyData or whatever.
        button1.PerformClick();
    }
```