# Web browser control: Detecting changes in form content

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

A **form** contains many elements, such as labels, Textbox, radio options box etc

**How do you detect the user has changed a textbox input value, or has choosen a radio option within the content of a web browser control?** (not the winform itself).

Do you handle a winform event for when the mouse clicked or keyboard keys pressed? or is there a better way to detect changes in the web browser content?

Comment: I read you as saying clearly that detecting a change inside the WebBrowser control is one goal : but when you ask about WinForms events, mouse-click, keypress, I am not sure if you are now speaking of a scenario in which the WebBrowser control no longer has "focus" and "something" on the Form is receiving those events. Could you clarify this a little ? Take a look at my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474586/how-can-i-make-a-hotkey-trigger-a-winforms-button/2474698#2474698 on using the WebBrowser 'PreviewKeyDown event : might be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "quick and easy" ways, but IMHO, a better way is to load the state of the form into javascript variables (on load), and then compare only the elements you are interested in, when navigating away, or whatever.

For example, there may be some fields that aren't so relevant (say, a different value in a minor drop-down box) but some that are very important (i.e. the contents of this message box).

It's fairly trivial to do anyway; just check the values you have currently (on the given event you are capturing, i.e. browser close) and then compare them with the ones you saved.

Comment: What about doing this for a keypressed or mouse move event?----------------

if (webBrowser1..Document.GetElementById("NAME").GetAttribute("value") != strDefaultNameValue){

// field changed
}

Comment: Seems a bit wasteful to do it for every keypress, doesn't it?